# How to get range cell in one column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

This is the code :

```
var values = [[ ph, sd, sg, qz, str ]];
var Rangeisi = shtdb.getRangeList(['C3:C6','C9']);
if(id="id001"){Rangeisi.setValues(values);
   return }
```

And this is the result :

> TypeError: Rangeisi.setValues is not a function

But when I use this code :

```
var values = [[ ph, sd, sg, qz, str ]];
var Rangeisi = shtdb.getRange(['A1:E1']);
if(id="id001"){Rangeisi.setValues(values);
  return }
```

It works!

My question is: how to select range (C3,C4,C5,C6,C9) to set values `[ ph, sd, sg, qz, str ]` ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow madam Rehandhika Arya Pratama. Please reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for asking a good question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `setValues()` method of a `RangeList` only `setValue()` which set each cell in the range to the same value.

The following example shows how to use a range list but it is limited to your specific example shown in your question.  It would probably need to be modifed for different `RangeList`.

Since the first range in the range list is C3:C6 i construct a 2D array of those value.  And since the last range in the range list is on C9 I still construct a 2D array of that value to use the `setValues()` method of `Range`.  I wrap both of those in an array to match the number of ranges in the range list.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let ph = 1;
    let sd = 2;
    let sg = 3;
    let qz = 4;
    let str = 5;
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let shtdb = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var values = [ [ [ph], [sd], [sg], [qz] ], [ [str] ] ]; 
    var Rangeisi = shtdb.getRangeList(['C3:C6','C9']); 
    let id = "id001";
    if(id="id001"){
      Rangeisi.getRanges().forEach( (range,index) => {
          range.setValues(values[index]);
        }
      );
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference:

- [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [RangeList.getRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#getRanges())

Comment: Result "Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. This data has 5 rows, but the range has 4 rows."

Comment: If you copy my script exactly it will work.  I tested it.  Make sure you have all the array braces as shown.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply this:

```
function test() {
    let ph = 1;
    let sd = 2;
    let sg = 3;
    let qz = 4;
    let str = 5;
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var values = [[ph], [sd], [sg], [qz], [str]];
    sh.getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
}
```